# How to use Resolve over custom domain

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mathematica-8, wolfram-language

```
A = {1,2,3,4}

ForAll[x, Element[A,x], x+1>0 ]

Resolve[%]
```

The above code gives me the following error:

> Unable to resolve the domain or region membership condition {1,2,3,4}[Element]x.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the arguments to `Element[A,x]` backwards, because `A` is your domain and `x` is an element of that domain. Just reversing those is not sufficient to eliminate the error message, but this appears to be enough.

```
A = {1,2,3,4};
ForAll[x, Element[x,Integers]&&0<x<5, x+1>0 ];
Resolve[%]
```

which returns `True`

Comment: Thank you for your response @Bill. I see that you mean; however the problem that I have is that I need it to be within a specific domain. For example what if the domain has unsorted numbers like -1,3,5,10,49,35,-84. I tried For[x, MemberQ[A,x], x+1<0 ] but it does not work

Comment: I other words, I need the value x to be an element of the set A not a member of all integers

Comment: I believe I understood what you want. It is possible that you can't get what you want using `ForAll[x, Element[x,A],...]`. Perhaps you can get what you want in another way.

Comment: This `Resolve[ForAll[x,x==-1||x==3||x==5||x==10||x==49||x==35||x==-84,x+1>0]]` does correctly return `False`. This `Resolve[ForAll[x,x==1||x==3||x==5||x==10||x==49||x==35||x==84,x+1>0]]` does correctly return `True`. This `Resolve[ForAll[x,x==-1||x==3||x==5||9<=x<=10,x+1>=0]]` cannot be decided.